# Как пишется слово «гастроуик-энд», «гастро-уик-энд»....?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов

Как пишется слово «гастроуик-энд», «гастро-уик-энд» (так говорит Грамота)....?

Comment: *Всё на месте)* — тогда будет "флоссиЮ". Это я не вас, а Егора спрашивал, просто процитировал его текст. Почему переводить ники плохо? Потому что это не имена, их не принято переводить, это логины на сайте, чтобы войти. А главное — чтобы всем было понятно (мне не было). Их и переводить сложно, потому что в нике могут быть любые символы. Попробуйте перевести: *us#er5645*. Стоит ли переводить? Другое дело — когда ник представляет собою имя.

Comment: А Вы Олеедд?...или же лучше латиницей...?

Comment: Лучше латиницей, потому что это оригинал — ещё одна важная причина, а оригинальность очень ценится в мире. Удвоение, потому что "oled" иногда на сайтах уже занято, чтобы не путаться, где какой ник.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Справочник Лопатина:
Недопустимо слитное написание с приставкой или первой частью сложного слова, **если вторая часть слова содержит дефис**. Слитное написание должно заменяться дефисным, в результате чего возникают написания с двумя дефисами. Например, следует писать: *полу-конференц-зал, полу-социал-демократы, ультра-ура-патриот, радио-мюзик-холл, теле-пресс-конференция, теле-ток-шоу, анти-социал-демократический, лже-тред-юнионистский, псевдо-историко-революционный*.
http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=80

Приставка "гастро" не требует дефис, но его необходимо поставить из-за того, что один дефис уже имеется, так что Грамота права.